# Build Failed after adding Kapsel Plugins to Cordova Project - Could not find SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=12.0"

Tags: windows, cordova, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, windows-mobile

I'm trying to make a Windows Cordova build using cmd but I'm getting below errors. Can any of you please guide me on how to fix this issue.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(
2377,5): error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=12.0".

No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1

PS: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017.

Comment: Do you use developer command prompt for vs? If so, what's the format of the command. And what's the result if we build it in IDE. For MSB3774, have you checked if the sdk exists.

Comment: What kind of platform you choose. UWP or Window phone? And make sure the project which fails with error above have added reference to VC++ 2013 runtime package.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT - Yes, I've used developer command prompt for vs and ran the command "Cordova run windows". I've checked and the SDK exists.

I'm using UWP, I've tried by adding VC++ 2013 reference to my project but still fails with the error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=12.0".

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT - I'm using Cordova and Kapsel Plugins in my project. If I remove Kapsel plugins it makes a build but if I include Kapsel plugins it won't. Do I need to install any tools or plugins in VS to support kapsel?

Comment: What's version of Kapsel sdk.I find some info about it but related to VS2015. And i'm not sure what level it is supported in VS. And if you just create a simple sample project with Kapsel plugin? Same issue persist?

Comment: Kapsel SDK Version is 3. I've uninstalled VS 2017 and I'm trying with VS 2015 now but still it gives errors. Tried creating a sample project with Kapsel Plugin but no luck  and the issue still exists.

Comment: It seems this issue result from the Kapsel Plugin. I'm not familiar with Kapsel plugin. So maybe i have to test it at my side later. In addition: This title could be better like "Build failed after adding kaspel plugin to cordova project " or what.